# Typescript and Angular2-highcharts: Property 'series' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: typescript, angular2-highcharts

When i try to implement the following plunkr in Angular, i get the following error message.

```
Property 'series' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OQSFSKisIIWAH0megy4d?p=preview

i've installed "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
and the typing "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.5",

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The the compiler does not know if the property `series` is present in `this.options` when you type it as `Object`.

To overcome this you can either remove the typing for the property (the lazy way out):

```
class AppComponent {

    options: any;
}
```

Or you can let the compiler infer the type from the object by assigning it directly so `this.options` will be typed properly:

```
class AppComponent {

    options = {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        series: ...
        // ...
    };
}
```

Or define the type of `options` in an interface:

```
interface Options {
    series: any[], // Should be typed to the shape of a series instead of `any`
    // and type other props like "chart", "title"
}
class AppComponent {

    options: Options;

    constructor() {
        this.options = {
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            series: ...
            // ...
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In case someone finds it useful**

Declare chart in your component like

```
export class DemoComponent {
  chart: Chart;
```

And add type option in series like

```
this.chart = new Chart({
  ...,
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Line 1',
      data: [1, 2, 3],
      type: 'line'
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case to make line chart working, I was using `[runOutsideAngular]="true"`.

```
<highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions.trends" [runOutsideAngular]="true"
            style="width: 100%; height: 300px; display: block;"
            [ngStyle]="{'opacity': chartOptions.trends.series[0].data.length === 0 ? 0 : 1}">
          </highcharts-chart>
```

this works fine in **dev** but while production it was throwing the same error

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'SeriesAbandsOptions'
```

casting `chartOptions.trends` to type `any` solved the issue.